# Difficulties installing SOAPpy module

Tags: python, windows, python-module, soappy

I am very new to python and have been figuring out how to install modules.I have been trying to install the SOAPpy module and have only had success with the required modules fpconst, wstools, and setuptools(not mentioned as required, but still ended up being required).

I am getting an error when I try and install the SOAPpy module.

```
Traceback <most recent call last>: 
 File "...\setup.py", line 43, in module <module>
  __version__ = load_version()
 File "...\setup.py", line 35 in load_version
  execfile(filename, d.__dict__)
IOError: [Errno 2] Unable to load the version number (no such file or directory):
'...\\src\\SOAPpy\\version.py'
```

Not sure what i should do to fix this.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you on Windows? If so, don't expand the .zip archive with the built-in Windows unzip utility, it cannot handle very long paths. Download winzip or winrar and unzip the archive with those utilities.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [SOAPpy's `setup.py` file](http://sourceforge.net/p/pywebsvcs/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/SOAPpy/setup.py), it tries to import `SOAPpy.version`. This doesn't work if you're calling it from somewhere else. Try running it directly in the SOAPpy directory because Python adds your current working directory to `sys.path`. For example:

```
cd C:\Users\eclaird\Download\SOAPpy\  # The folder with setup.py
python.exe setup.py install
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I eventually found what the issue was. I had to get some other required modules for the install to work, also the tar file I got was missing directories, so I found the completed version on Github.